# Get name of SKTextureatlas

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktextureatlas

Can I programmatically get the name of a `SKTextureAtlas`?

If printed, the atlas results in: `SKTextureAtlas> 'PurpleBalloonGirl' 168 textures: (...)`. So, the name of the atlas is there `(PurpleBalloonGirl)` but can I access it directly via code?